# open graph properties not recognised by Facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've spent a week reading stackoverflow posts and using the facebook og debugger without any success.

If you go to https://www.photrea.com and click inspect, you see that I declared all necessary og types in my header:
[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEC3C.png)
If you then try to share this link on Facebook, or if you go to the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), you see that it doesn't process the raw tags the right way.

UPDATE:

The Facebook debugger points out that FB reads my home.js.erb javascript file instead of the html file. But why...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're defining it as

`<meta property="og:title" content="...">`

where as it should be:

`<meta name="og:title" content="..." />`

So just switch the `property` with a `name` and it'll work.

And here's a list of common OG tags taken from one of my websites:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="JavaScript Code to go" />
<meta name="og:type" content="article" />
<meta name="og:image" content="/images/share.png" />
<meta name="og:description" content="Javascript code to go: Find updated snippets for common JavaScript use cases." />
<meta name="og:site_name" content="Code to go" />
```